# How do remove the CD / DVD install as a source for apt-get packages when installing new features?

Tags: installation, apt, package-management

I'm running a Ubuntu server (9.0.4 'Jaunty') as a VMware image.

It's a real pain on the odd occasion I need to install a new package to have to fish out the install CD-ROM, and make it available to the VMware image so I can continue the package install.

Is there any way to take the original installation media out of the list of source packages - I'm assuming all packages will be available on the internet.

Thanks.

Comment: forgot to mention it's a headless server (no User Interface installed) - so if it's possible I'll need a command line solution

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, you can remove the CD-ROM (or or original installation media) from the `sources.list`

Edit the `sources.list` file with the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And near the top, comment out the line that looks like this:

```
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 9.04 _Jaunty Jackalope_ - Release i386 (20090421.1)]/ jaunty main restricted
```

(comment is a hash (`#`) - so pop one of these at the start of the `deb cdrom: ...` line)

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit the nano text editor, pressing <kbd>y</kbd> to save your changes

Then finally you'll need to run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To update your package lists.

Comment: This will work (if you finish by running `sudo apt-get update`) but for most users the graphical way (binW's answer) is vastly preferable.

Comment: thanks for the tip about the extra step, I've updated my answer

Comment: 9.04 is no longer supported

Answer (score 5):

#### For 12.04 and 12.10

This feature i.e auto enabling of the installation medium as software sources is disabled in this release. The section is empty now by default and will say this:

> **To install from CD-ROM or DVD, insert the medium into the drive**

Here is a screenshot added

[image]

I think, this will be continued in the coming releases also.

Answer (score 4):

Go to System->Aministration->Software sources. Go to **Ubuntu Software** tab, at the bottom of the tab there is an option for CD/DVD. Selecting/deselecting it enables and disables CD/DVD as software source. Just un-check this option and your system will not look for Ubuntu CD or DVD

[image]

Comment: this will not work for 9.04

Comment: 09.04 does not have any official repositories (only non-updated unofficial). This will end up in errors due to main, universe, restricted and multiverse not being able to find the servers. For older releases see: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/

Answer (score 3):

**Official support for Ubuntu 9.04 ended in October 2010.**

If you need to install new packages you may be able to download Debian packages that may still be compatible but for a proper maintenance including security updates a distribution upgrade is recommended.

You would have to upgrade to 9.10 before being able to upgrade to 10.04 LTS (the actual long term support version). Unfortunately support for 9.10 has also ended by the end of April 2011.

Therefore it would be best practise to reinstall your Ubuntu with 10.04 LTS server. With a backup of your `/home` before you do this you are able to preserve most of your individual settings.

If for any reason you need to stay with 9.04 you have no other option than keeping your CD-ROM as only source.