# Need 'Ubuntu 15.10 _Wily Werewolf_ - Release amd64 ' on USB

Tags: apt, usb, dvd

Whenever I try the command `sudo apt-get install -f` I get the message

> Media change: please insert the disc labeled
>    'Ubuntu 15.10 _ Wily Werewolf_ - release amd 64 (20151021)'
>    in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press enter.

Now, my question is can I use a USB instead of a DVD in this case?
Because  I've got the .iso named above already on a boot USB.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like your CD is listed in Software Sources, you'd better remove it (e.g. [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/42445) way). It isn't needed as a package source anymore once you've finished installation as you can get newer versions and more packages from the online repositories.

You can also mount the iso to this folder with `sudo mount -o loop image.iso /media/cdrom` but I believe it's the wrong way to solve this problem.

Comment: This was a nicely written answer, although I marked the question as a duplicate.  Please when possible, include the instructions for how to accomplish a task rather than just a link to an answer.