# can't install fglrx

Tags: ati, gpu-driver, ubuntu-drivers

when i try to install fglrx with synaptic package manager a have the following errors:

Please insert the disk labeled:
Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS *Trusty Tahr* - Beta amd64 (20150805)
in drive /media/cdrom/

[firstER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8Iil.png)
[secondER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc8hE.png)

Comment: I resolve the problem, I don't have CD-ROM at my laptop because I made it an upgrade with an SSD and I removed the CD-ROM.

The solution was to remove the CD-ROM from the Sources List.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the cdrom entry from the sources.list and you can do this using below syntax:

```
sudo sed -i '/cdrom/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then check content

```
grep -v '#' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove the CD-ROM from the Sources List.

Go to System->Aministration->Software sources. Go to Ubuntu Software tab, at the bottom of the tab there is an option for CD/DVD. Selecting/deselecting it enables and disables CD/DVD as software source. Just un-check this option and your system will not look for Ubuntu CD or DVD

https://askubuntu.com/a/42446/477203