# How to resolve this problem? "Failed to download repository information"

Tags: updates, update-manager

i try to update something and when i change the download server, it says my software is out-of-date and i press reload after it the download is interupted and saying this:

Check your internet connection:

> W:The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS *Xenial Xerus* - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial Release' does not have a Release file.,
>
> W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.,
>
> E:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS *Xenial Xerus* - Release amd64 (20160719)/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs,
>
> E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

sorry for my bad english.
thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with sudo apt get update: The repository cdrom... does not have a Release file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776721/problem-with-sudo-apt-get-update-the-repository-cdrom-does-not-have-a-releas)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to download repository information due to missing CDROM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125111/failed-to-download-repository-information-due-to-missing-cdrom)

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration seems to include the CD you installed from, which is no longer mounted, and is useless for updates.

Either ignore the error (after all, `They have been ignored, or old ones used instead`. or find the line(s) in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` that mention "`deb cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS ...`" and comment (with a `#` in the first column) or delete these lines.