# Unable to install google chrome and libappindicator1

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, deb

I have recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my computer, and I tried installing google chrome but I wasn't able to. Here's what I got.

```
$ sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/google_chrome.deb
(Reading database ... 207470 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../Downloads/google_chrome.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (55.0.2883.87-1) over (55.0.2883.87-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
 google-chrome-stable depends on libappindicator1; however:
  Package libappindicator1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
```

So I tried installing libappindicator1, and this is what I got

```
$ sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
E: Type '@deb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Type '@deb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I am totally new to Linux, so I have no idea what that means and how to fix it. A help would be appreciated.

Comment: To add to the question, I have tried installing chrome through the 'ubuntu software', but it didn't proceed so I rebooted. Could be related because using apt-get install on anything just shows the same error after that.

Comment: The Ubuntu Software Center is just a graphical program which is using the same libraries/logic as apt/dpkg -- so it probably fails in the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`google-chrome-stable`** is available on a 3rd Party Repository:Google  Chrome (for Stable).

Follow the instruction for installation:

1. Add Key:

   ```
   wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
2. Set repository:

   ```
   sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
   ```
3. Install package:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update 
   sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
   ```

### OR do it using `.deb` file

1.Go to https://www.google.com/intl/en-US/chrome/browser/

2.Click Download and a small window will pop up with some download options.

- choose `.deb` file for Ubuntu.

3.It will automatically installed after you open it using **Ubuntu software center**

Comment: I try this and I get this :   No se puede iniciar la conexión a dl.google.com:80 (2607:f8b0:4008:803::200e). - connect (101: La red es inaccesible) [IP: 2607:f8b0:4008:803::200e 80]
Descargados 102 kB en 2min 0s (849 B/s)         
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
W: Fallo al obtener http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  No se puede iniciar la conexión a dl.google.com:80 (2607:f8b0:4008:803::200e). - connect (101: La red es inaccesible) [IP: 2607:f8b0:4008:803::200e 80]

Comment: Well, in that case, use the ".deb file download" option @YosvedVillar and give a hit if it works

Answer (score 7):

**1.** I downloaded the `.deb` file from [the official web page](https://www.google.com/chrome).

**2.** And later I entered the command you've already written:

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

(I have 64-bit architecture thats why I downloaded the amd64)

**3.** Then I downloaded the missing file

```
sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
```

Then I got an error about, libappindicator7... and APT suggested I run the command:

```
apt-get -f install
```

Without arguments.

Next it asks if you want to install both `libappindicator1` and `libappindicator7`. You type `y`.

**4.** And finally you execute the first command again...

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Then it works!

Note: I didn't tell you to run those commands with libappindicator first.. because maybe you would get another error about "missing files" so the first `dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` would tell you what you needed.

Comment: @Zanna Thank you for the corrections! I appreciate it.

Comment: No worries... hope I understood your answer correctly

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and run

> sudo apt --fix-broken install

this command install all the missing packages

Answer (score 0):

By the look of it, that's just a typo in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list` (an `@` has sneaked in at the start of a line). It might still be there but apt sometimes isn't very consistent about always throwing the same errors.

To explain something else you've mentioned, `dpkg -i` installs a single package if all its dependencies are present, but it won't install the dependencies for you. The `apt` tools by contrast tend to manage the whole process.

Getting automatic security updates, and this, are the two reasons it's usually best to add a repo to a sources list and automatically use apt to install from them. (Although when you do that you are trusting the repo owner to never include malicious software in their repo, or have it taken over by someone who does).

Comment: I should also mention that Ubuntu includes the `chromium-browser` package, which is almost identical to Google Chrome (although sometimes a little out of date) and much less hassle to install.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Debian Stretch and it was caused by the fact I had a unauthenticated cdrom repository in /etc/apt/sources.list. The solution was to comment it out.

The answer that helped me is: https://askubuntu.com/a/803509

Answer (score 0):

Running this command resolved the dependency problem for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libappindicator3-1 libindicator3-7
```

Chrome version: 67.0.3396.87 (Official Build) (64-bit). It's the latest at this moment - June 24, 2018.

Looks like these two packages have a circular dependency between them and need to be installed by a single apt-get command.

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package_metas/alphabetical

Search for the required packages click on the links, select the version that you need. The required package can be directly installed by clicking on "APT INSTALL" button. You don't have to download them.

Then you can run `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-42-0-2311-90-64-bit-multi-ubu.deb` in the terminal, if you have already downloaded the package.

I too faced the same problem but later installed the required packages one by one and at last install google-chrome. It installed without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

none of the above worked for me,

`sudo apt-get install libappindicator3-1:amd64 libindicator3-7:amd64`

is the line that fixed the broken dependencies in my case

Answer (score 0):

You need to install it manually

Download package:

```
curl -p --insecure "http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/liba/libappindicator/libappindicator1_0.4.92-7_amd64.deb" --output libappindicator1_0.4.92-7_amd64.deb
```

Then install it:

```
sudo dpkg --install libappindicator1_0.4.92-7_amd64.deb
```

I hope this helps)