# Can't install .deb version of Chrome

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, deb, drive

I've been trying to install .deb chrome file (`google-chrome-stable_current_amd.64.deb`). It is saved in my Downloads, so I tried this command

```
sudo apt-get install ~/Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_amd.64.deb
```

After reading the package list it responds:

```
E: Unsupported file /home/stockton/Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_amd.64.deb given on command line
```

I don't know why it says `E: file`, I though Linux drives and files are not named after letters like Windows drives, for example 'C:' but idk I can still be wrong. I did have Windows 10 before I booted Ubuntu.

Any help will be great.

Comment: Copy the file to your Home directory (`/home/stockton`) and run `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome* && sudo apt install -f`

Comment: The `E:` is not related to Windows drive letters - it simply denotes an **E**rror condition

Comment: `apt-get` can't install .deb files.

Comment: Pankaj Gautam's solution works for me, 17.04 https://askubuntu.com/questions/868272/unable-to-install-google-chrome-and-libappindicator1?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: And it looks like you made a typo in the command. It is not `amd.64.deb`, it is `amd64.deb`.

Comment: this is a repost of a previous question by the same user.  PS- the command is `dpkg` not `apt`

Comment: Run `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: Modern `apt` is able to install .deb files directly and pull the dependencies.

Comment: All the other answers fail to mention this, but do a `chmod 777 google-chrome-stable_current_amd.64.deb` on your downloaded file. And then you can install it normally.

Answer (score 10):

The conventional way is to install using `dpkg`. It is a new feature of `apt` to install from deb files. That's why the correct syntax is not always clear. `man apt` doesn't tell much either.

So a guaranteed way is to copy the deb file to your Home directory and running

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

If it is the first time you install Chrome, you will get some error messages regarding missing dependencies. You can fix it by

```
sudo apt install -f
```

Instead of copying to Home you can use the path

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

**Update:** It looks like the solution is easier. OP made a typo in the command. The file name is wrong `amd.64.deb` :-)

So it is likely that the initial command with the correct file will work as well.

Answer (score 2):

You normally don't download debs and install them in linux, like you are used to in windows with exe files.

You add a repository (or ppa, where available), update the software list and install the software. This way you also get updates through the added repository.

For Google Chrome, do this:

open a terminal <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

add the repository key:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

add the chrome repository with this command:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
```

update software list:

```
sudo apt update
```

install Google Chrome (stable):

```
sudo apt install google-chrome-stable
```

Done.

Pro Tip: Paste to console with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>

[edit] forgot adding repository key, sorry.[/edit]