# How do I install openjdk 9 jdk

Tags: apt, java, openjdk

I tried installing openjdk-9-jdk on ubuntu 16.10 desktop with:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-9-jdk
```

and I had this error at the tail end

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  ubuntu-core-launcher
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java fonts-dejavu-extra java-common libatk-wrapper-java
  libatk-wrapper-java-jni libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libgif7 libgnome-2-0
  libgnome2-common libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libice-dev liborbit-2-0
  libpthread-stubs0-dev libsm-dev libx11-dev libx11-doc libxau-dev libxcb1-dev
  libxdmcp-dev libxt-dev openjdk-9-jdk-headless openjdk-9-jre
  openjdk-9-jre-headless x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev
  xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
Suggested packages:
  default-jre libbonobo2-bin desktop-base libgnomevfs2-bin libgnomevfs2-extra
  gamin | fam gnome-mime-data libice-doc libsm-doc libxcb-doc libxt-doc
  openjdk-9-demo openjdk-9-source visualvm icedtea-8-plugin
  fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho ttf-wqy-microhei | ttf-wqy-zenhei
  fonts-indic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java fonts-dejavu-extra java-common libatk-wrapper-java
  libatk-wrapper-java-jni libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libgif7 libgnome-2-0
  libgnome2-common libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libice-dev liborbit-2-0
  libpthread-stubs0-dev libsm-dev libx11-dev libx11-doc libxau-dev libxcb1-dev
  libxdmcp-dev libxt-dev openjdk-9-jdk openjdk-9-jdk-headless openjdk-9-jre
  openjdk-9-jre-headless x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev
  xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
0 upgraded, 31 newly installed, 0 to remove and 32 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,068 B/104 MB of archives.
After this operation, 255 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 libpthread-stubs0-dev amd64 0.3-4
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpthread-stubs/libpthread-stubs0-dev_0.3-4_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Thereafter i tried:

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

and it came up with this error again:

```
Err:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Checksum-FileSize:82209 [weak]
   - SHA256:f25acc3529121d89c7485b605c9a9c787cf29b7c67eb2bd9988ae892f545966e
   - SHA1:8b8147645408e5ec067d946eb0c5c2e7f65ec25b [weak]
   - MD5Sum:c3f865ffb3890722ec4d86634b7883c3 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:a2af292754b8597d0dc39483bbe1a6e050461fa219799f2e8fa1eed4d917cc97
   - SHA1:040acf2800bca6794af3de55cdac79f8effd4ab5 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:28ddca688e614c737b7d06cf93d33ebb [weak]
   - Checksum-FileSize:74295 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Tue, 04 Apr 2017 02:37:51 +0000
  Release file created at: Mon, 10 Apr 2017 20:19:45 +0000
Ign:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports/main amd64 Packages  
Ign:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports/main amd64 Packages
Err:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports/main amd64 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Fetched 1,113 kB in 5min 26s (3,412 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 16.10 _Yakkety Yak_ - Release amd64 (20161012.2) yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 16.10 _Yakkety Yak_ - Release amd64 (20161012.2)/dists/yakkety/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety-updates/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar.gz  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Checksum-FileSize:82209 [weak]
    - SHA256:f25acc3529121d89c7485b605c9a9c787cf29b7c67eb2bd9988ae892f545966e
    - SHA1:8b8147645408e5ec067d946eb0c5c2e7f65ec25b [weak]
    - MD5Sum:c3f865ffb3890722ec4d86634b7883c3 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:a2af292754b8597d0dc39483bbe1a6e050461fa219799f2e8fa1eed4d917cc97
    - SHA1:040acf2800bca6794af3de55cdac79f8effd4ab5 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:28ddca688e614c737b7d06cf93d33ebb [weak]
    - Checksum-FileSize:74295 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Tue, 04 Apr 2017 02:37:51 +0000
   Release file created at: Mon, 10 Apr 2017 20:19:45 +0000
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Please, how do I resolve this?

Comment: I think you have an error in this repo `archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports/main amd64 Packages` disable it and try again

Comment: Thank you for the response, please how do I disable it?

Comment: Go to `system settings --> software & updates --> updates` To get there look at the top right hand corner of your screen for the power button. Click that and you should see `system settings`

Comment: What java version do you currently have: `java --version` to check

Comment: I disabled yakkety-backports, but no difference.

Comment: No version of java installed yet                            olanrewaju@olanrewaju-VM:~$ java -version
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.9-jre-headless
 * gcj-6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-9-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>

Comment: Lets do an update first: `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, then `sudo apt update`, and finally `sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: If I ask is it necessary to install `openjdk-9-jdk`

Comment: Sorry my response is late.  I am learning hadoop and I needed to install java, so I thought the latest version would be the best.

Comment: i will try the update process and give feedback. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with sudo apt get update: The repository cdrom... does not have a Release file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776721/problem-with-sudo-apt-get-update-the-repository-cdrom-does-not-have-a-releas)