# 18.04 ISO has installed 17.10

Tags: iso

I downloaded 18.04.3 from the main Ubuntu pages and the file downloaded is called 18.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso so I know I selected the right thing... but after the installed has completed I have Ubuntu17.10 installed. I noticed it doing the first apt-get update.. and found that

/etc/apt/sources.list

contained the following

```
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 17.10 _Artful Aardvark_ - Release amd64 (20180105.1)]/ artful main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful main restricted
```

My files from the previous version have gone so I know the disk reformat completed OK.

I did a search but couldn't find anyone reporting the same ? Just mentioning it in case it's a build issue? Has anyone else seen this or have I done something daft?

Steve

Comment: Where did you download it from?  The official site? an official mirror? or somewhere google pointed you to.  Did you verify the media after download (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) as I suspect this would have shown it was a bad download, unless you wrote the wrong ISO to your install-media.

Comment: The first line of your provided sources implies it's a very pre-release daily dated 2018-Jan-05, ie. a daily system intended to be used for tested, and was replaced the next day with a newer one. 18.04 alpha's were produced that day, however they would have **NO** lines referring to '*artful*' if it was a 18.04 ISO on it though, so what you have is unofficial/bad is my guess thus my first comment, **OR** it was the 17.10.1 ISO (which did have dailies produced; I can't recall when though)

Comment: Downloaded from the official Ubuntu Site https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?country=GB&version=18.04.3&architecture=amd64 the 'lsb_release -a' shows. Description: Ubuntu 17.10. I will look at the media verification ASAP and post back.

Comment: Tried to follow the instructions to verify the ISO and failed.. Will try again tomorrow. Could be the beer inhibiting my command line skills.

Comment: Tried again one last time and got the following output from the verification steps - ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso: OK. It feels like the ISO is correct but that it failed to remove the 17.10 system I had in place when I started the clean install. I'm going to build a fresh system in virtual box and see what happens.

Comment: Was this a new install?  or did you have 17.10 already on the system (thus you're booting into an old system already present and not the newer one).  I can't see how a 18.04.3 ISO downloaded would morph itself into a 17.10.1 unless a user-mistake was made (your end), or a MITM type attack which the verification should detect.  18.04.x was bionic beaver (so you'll see a beaver's pic), 17.10.x was artful aardvark (so you'll see an aardvark pic in wallpaper) so you'd have picked pre-install anyway I'd expect by wallpaper.  *fyi:  the date of the daily does match up with dailies for 17.10.1*

Comment: I tried the install again, and as you say the wall paper was a give away.. The USB boot media I created from the ISO was for 17.10.x So I must have messed up when creating the boot media! Got there in the end thanks again for everyones support. I formatted the USB and then created the boot media again. This time the install have a bionic beaver and after the install everything looks good ! Sorry.. user error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with sudo apt get update: The repository cdrom... does not have a Release file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776721/problem-with-sudo-apt-get-update-the-repository-cdrom-does-not-have-a-releas)

Answer (score 0):

run this command to sure what version are you using:

```
cat /etc/lsb_release
```

if it has ubuntu 18 so you are right.

you can type `pwd` and `df -h` to sure where are you and what is your root partition.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 18, there is Ubuntu Core 18, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Ubuntu 18.10 which is EOL and this not right, but if it reports Ubuntu 18 (of which there is none) then I'd be suspicious it's not right.

Comment: I mean anything with 18 not 17. so you are right and your version is not 17...

Comment: ... Or run `lsb_release -a`

Comment: 18.10 is EOL too & how is that good?

Comment: I can't understand your goal @guiverc. as you say : I downloaded 18.04.3... so what's wrong. do you want to see the last 3 in the result? I thought your problem is about ubuntu 17 in your sourcelist!

Comment: You stated "anything with 18 not 17" - Ubuntu 18.10 is EOL just like 17.10 and is thus bad, also a system that reports itself as "Ubuntu 18" I wouldn't trust as it's not an official release (*Ubuntu Core 18* is valid but not 'Ubuntu 18').  Google will send people to unofficial sites that offer unofficial ISO's for downloads, and whilst some are unaltered, there could very well be some that are malicious. Clues like an invalid "Ubuntu 18" release are a warning, as is getting a 17.10.1 pre-release ISO when you tried to get something else.

Comment: search in duckduckgo.it's better. and as you can see in https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle ubuntu 18.04 will suppor untill middle 2020 and security suppport until 2028. also, you can type in terminal (crtl+alt+T) do-release-upgrade to upgrade. it's easy with internet.

Comment: I have now used the same media to install a fresh virtual box and it installed 18.04 correctly. So the issue I have is that when using the 18.04.03 media to do a clean install over a copy of 17.10 it has left the old system, wiped the files e.g. user folder contents but not actually installed 18.04.03 over the top? Strange. I will try again but now I know its not the media I guess there is nothing for anyone else to worry about. Thanks all for your help..

Comment: your welcome, don't forget to check as solve...

Answer (score 0):

User error. I had the right ISO but failed when creating the USB boot media and it left an old copy of ubuntu in place. Tried again and all OK.