# Ubuntu Studio 20.10 installation failed "does not have a Release file"

Tags: apt, system-installation, 20.10, ubuntu-studio

I tried to install it on a Lenovo Ideapad 330s (Intel CPU, NVIDIA GPU, installing from USB created with UNetbootin from default file verified with the SHA hash). Any known fixes to this error? Thanks :)

Here is the error message (I tried to type it out, might have typos):

```
Installation Failed

External command finished with errors.

Command apt-get update finished with exit code 100. 
Output: 
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu-Studio 20.10 _Groovy Gorilla_ -Release amd64 (20201022) bionic InRelease 
Ign:2 cdrom://Ubuntu-Studio 20.10 _Groovy Gorilla_ -Release amd64 (20201022) groovy InRelease 
Err:3  cdrom://Ubuntu-Studio 20.10 _Groovy Gorilla_ -Release amd64 (20201022) bionic Release 
Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs 
Hit:4  cdrom://Ubuntu-Studio 20.10 _Groovy Gorilla_ -Release amd64 (20201022) groovy Release 
Reading package lists… 
E: The repository ‘cdrom://Ubuntu-Studio 20.10 _Groovy Gorilla_ -Release amd64 (20201022) bionic Release’ does not have a Release file.
```

Comment: Commenting out the lines with "cdrom" in /etc/apt/sources.list before attempting installation did not fix this

Comment: `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` add it to your question please.

Comment: Sorry, I already overwrote that USB (installed Kubuntu+Ubuntu Studio installer instead, which works). There was 5 lines in the sources.list file, two with "cdrom" in them (groovy multiverse and bionic main restricted or something like that), and three others without "cdrom" (all were something Universe or something like that).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with sudo apt get update: The repository cdrom... does not have a Release file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776721/problem-with-sudo-apt-get-update-the-repository-cdrom-does-not-have-a-releas)

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Software and Updates**
[image: Software and Updates]

In the **Ubuntu Software** tab, look for the cdrom, if it’s checked, uncheck it.
[image: Ubuntu Software tab]

Now, open up a terminal and open the file `sources.list` using

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

If you find a line starting with `cdrom`, then comment it by putting `#` like this `#deb cdrom:....`

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save.

Finally, run the command

```
sudo apt update
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, doing this before the installation attempt not work, even the error message during installation of Ubuntu Studio didn't change.