# How can I solve "The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210209.1) focal Release' does not have a Release file"?

Tags: apt, updates

```
$ sudo apt update
E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210209.1) focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with sudo apt get update: The repository cdrom... does not have a Release file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776721/problem-with-sudo-apt-get-update-the-repository-cdrom-does-not-have-a-releas)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open Software & Updates, in the Ubuntu Software tab, uncheck Cdrom with Ubuntu 20.04 'Focal Fossa' under Installable from CD-ROM/DVD