# Can't download Exodus, Repo issue?

Tags: apt, updates, repository

I am trying to install the Exodus wallet from a `.deb` file as I thought that would be easier but, when I try to install it from Terminal, I receive this message:

```
E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20190805) bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How can I solve this and install the `.deb`?

Comment: The message is telling you the installation media is not present (ie. cdrom; even if installed from other media; convention refers to installation medium regardless of what was used, to be referred to as a cdrom). The date 2019-08-05 tells you the date of the [*installation*] ISO; ie. 18.04.3 or older media (latest is 2020-August for 18.04.5 but your system was installed with 18.04.3 media from 2019-August).  You can just disable it.  See CD/DVD Rom section in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu   And welcome to Ask Ubuntu & using Ubuntu, we're all new at some point :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with sudo apt get update: The repository cdrom... does not have a Release file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776721/problem-with-sudo-apt-get-update-the-repository-cdrom-does-not-have-a-releas)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things we’ll need to do. First, edit a file so that the update manager is not looking for a CD/DVD with updates, then add the correct repository for updates so you can have an up-to-date system.

You don’t *need* to use the command line for these steps but, if you would like to, here’s how:

1. Open Terminal (if it’s not already open)
2. Edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file with root privileges:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```

   <sub>**Note:** You do not need to use `vi`. If you prefer a different editor, such as `nano`, feel free to use it. Be sure to keep `sudo` up front, though.</sub>
3. Find the line that starts with `CDROM` and add a `#` at the start. You should now have a line that looks like:

   ```
   # cdrom://Ubuntu 18.04 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64
   ```
4. Save the file. If you are using `vi` and are unfamiliar with the commands, you save and exit by first pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit editing mode, then <kbd>:</kbd>⇢ <kbd>W</kbd>⇢<kbd>Q</kbd> (Write & Quit)

   You should now be back at the shell.

With that first step done, let’s add the correct repo for Ubuntu:

1. From the terminal, add the default repo:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
   ```
2. Update apt:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
3. If there are updates, you can install them with:

   ```
   sudo apt upgrade
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   sudo apt dist-upgrade
   ```

Now you might be ready to install Exodus. Rarely does a person need to jump through so many hoops ahead of time, but now the main stuff is complete.

1. Ensure you have the latest version of `libgconf` installed:

   ```
   sudo apt install libgconf-2-4
   ```
2. Download the `.deb` file from Exodus.com/download. It’s easiest from a browser but, if you want to do it via the command line:

   ```
   wget https://downloads.exodus.com/releases/exodus-linux-x64-21.7.2.deb
   ```
3. Install the application:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i exodus-linux-x64-21.7.2.deb
   ```
4. Open the application via the applications menu

That’s all there really is to it.