# Error while installing node js and npm lts version (UBUNTU 20.04 LTS Desktop)

Tags: package-management, updates, update-manager, nodejs, npm

I am getting an error whenever I am running this command-

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | sudo -E bash -
```

And here is the full error log:--

```
## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 16.x repo...


## Populating apt-get cache...

+ apt-get update
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210819) focal InRelease
Err:2 cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210819) focal Release
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

Err:16 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Ubuntu:/debbuild/Ubuntu_20.04  InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 08CF86BF009AAE2E
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210819) focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Ubuntu:/debbuild/Ubuntu_20.04  InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 08CF86BF009AAE2E
E: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Ubuntu:/debbuild/Ubuntu_20.04  InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Error executing command, exiting
```

How can i solve this issue? Its urgent, please someone help me out as I am a noob to ubuntu.

Comment: Any and all questions should include the version of Ubuntu and whether it is desktop or server.

Comment: The current version of ubuntu is 20.04 LTS desktop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with sudo apt get update: The repository cdrom... does not have a Release file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776721/problem-with-sudo-apt-get-update-the-repository-cdrom-does-not-have-a-releas) Also run `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 08CF86BF009AAE2E` .