# Facing problem to update software and can't get Ubuntu version 22.04

Tags: upgrade, updates

I'm facing a problem to update software and can't get Ubuntu version 22.04

[image: screenshot of my problem to update]

---

```
md@md-hp-laptop-15s-du3xxx:~$ ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d 
total 56
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 190 Aug 29 16:02 google-chrome.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 190 Aug 29 16:00 google-chrome.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 190 Aug 29 15:57 google-chrome.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  54 Aug 29 16:02 koha.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  54 Aug 29 16:00 koha.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  54 Aug 29 15:57 koha.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 132 Aug 29 16:02 libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 132 Aug 29 16:00 libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 132 Aug 29 15:57 libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 152 Aug 29 16:02 webupd8team-ubuntu-y-ppa-manager-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 152 Aug 29 16:00 webupd8team-ubuntu-y-ppa-manager-focal.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 120 Aug 29 16:02 zotero.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 120 Aug 29 16:00 zotero.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 120 Aug 29 15:57 zotero.list.save
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with sudo apt get update: The repository cdrom... does not have a Release file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776721/problem-with-sudo-apt-get-update-the-repository-cdrom-does-not-have-a-releas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the "*Software & Updates*" application. At the bottom, there's an "Installable from CD-ROM/DVD" section. Unlike the screenshot I'm sharing, you will have a selected option in that section.

Uncheck whatever is there.

You also have a customer repository added that uses a domain that doesn't resolve anywhere.

To fix that, in the same application you were in, go to the "Other Software" tab and search for an entry that mentions that `retorque` domain and uncheck it.

Close the application, and it will ask you to reload. Do that, and try updating your system again.

[image]

Comment: sorry but first 2 method i unchecked but in the 3rd section didn;t find the keyword "retorque"

Comment: after applied your method i get these :W: Failed to fetch https://apt.retorque.re/file/zotero-apt/./InRelease  Could not resolve 'apt.retorque.re'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: So stop adding repos that don't have content for your release and remove the ones you already added.

Comment: @DipuAlnur Can you run `ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d` and post the output of that in you question, please?

Comment: total 36
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  54 Jul 24 08:28 koha.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  54 Jul 24 08:26 koha.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  54 Jul 21 21:20 koha.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 132 Jul 24 08:28 libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 132 Jul 24 08:26 libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 132 Jul 21 21:20 libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 120 Jul 24 08:28 zotero.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 120 Jul 24 08:26 zotero.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 120 Jul 21 21:20 zotero.list.save