# Problem in downloading ROS

Tags: command-line, ros

Problem while running `sudo apt update`:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. Please copy and paste from the terminal into your question instead of posting a screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with sudo apt get update: The repository cdrom... does not have a Release file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776721/problem-with-sudo-apt-get-update-the-repository-cdrom-does-not-have-a-releas)