Ubuntu 24.04 dual boot is failing to install
I'm trying to install Ubuntu 24.04 alongside Windows 10. The installation is failing with the below error. I've been stuck for two days on this.
https://pastebin.com/ucMT82dV

Maybe a trivial question, but did you create a separate partition of your hard drive to put Ubuntu on?

Is this a fresh install of 24.04 or an upgrade from a previous version of Ubuntu? I think there is a problem getting source data from /cdrom.  Take a look at the question and answers @ https://askubuntu.com/questions/776721/problem-with-sudo-apt-get-update-the-repository-cdrom-does-not-have-a-releas
