# W: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170801) xenial Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: apt, updates

When I update with`sudo apt-get update` it comes up with a list of errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done                      
W: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170801) xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170801)/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First, those are warnings and not errors so you could ignore them if you chose.

You are getting them as I presume the CD is  not in the drive.

If they bother you, remove the CD from your sources.

See [How do remove the CD / DVD install as a source for apt-get packages when installing new features?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42441/how-do-remove-the-cd-dvd-install-as-a-source-for-apt-get-packages-when-install)