# X.Org driver getting crashed and I am not able to change the driver

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg

[image]

While palying video X.Org video driver is getting crashed. My entire display becomes blur and then black. I am unable to change the Nvidia driver; it is asking for media.

Please guide me with full instructions. I am a new user.

Comment: Try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics

But is seems - from the screenshot - that You do not have CDROM mounted...

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/42441/how-do-remove-the-cd-dvd-install-as-a-source-for-apt-get-packages-when-install

Comment: bodhi.zazen You are the best and saved my day