# I want to stop an installation on terminal

Tags: software-installation

Every time I type `sudo apt update` this information appears: The box was unticked when I check the software and updates

```
elizabeth@elizabeth:~$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Get:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]   
Get:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB] 
Fetched 252 kB in 1s (175 kB/s)                              
Reading package lists... Done
```

Is there a fix?

Comment: Please post the full output of `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: The graphic is a bit sloppy.

Comment: See if https://askubuntu.com/questions/42441/how-do-remove-the-cd-dvd-install-as-a-source-for-apt-get-packages-when-install helps.

Comment: Nothings changed

Comment: Here's a graphic https://imgur.com/a/xMccEvn

Comment: See if the answer posted below helps you.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! **;-)** Could you please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1142659/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions in the future... **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

Open software and updates and uncheck the option Installable from CD-ROM/DVD
[image]