# upgrade from 21.04 to 21.10

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I run the update manager from the terminal and I click the "Upgrade" button in its popup window, this is what happens in the terminal

```
update-manager -c
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

Comment: my queston is in English

The Ubuntu isntallation I'm running is set to Italian though

Comment: Try running `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 bash` before the command to translate it to English!

Comment: ok, I did as suggested and edited the question, thanks

Comment: Your system is not supported anymore, you have to upgrade through reinstalling, thats the only option!

Comment: Please ensure you've applied all upgrades as per the message; ie. `sudo apt update` to ensure software lists are updated (no errors or warnings were given) then `sudo apt full-upgrade` to ensure all available upgrades are applied. Assuming no error messages or warnings exist there; I'd try again (*if you get warnings of *holds* existing on any packages in messages; you'll need to revert/remove those holds).  *Do note there are cases where `apt upgrade` cannot apply all upgrades! which is why you need to use `full-upgrade`*

Comment: sudo apt update laments that it can't find cdrom://Ubuntu 20.10 _Groovy Gorilla_ - Release amd64 (20201022) groovy InRelease

Comment: partially, yes. Thank you

Comment: Comment out the CDROM; which is how installation media is referred to (*even if it was on thumb-drive or modern media; it's referred to as CDROM*). - the following will be helpful; but note HIRSUTE or 21.04 hasn't yet moved to old-releases; so the duplicate link isn't required *yet* (but will be in hours/days)  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/42441/how-do-remove-the-cd-dvd-install-as-a-source-for-apt-get-packages-when-install