# Cannot run sudo apt update

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates

I cannot update my Ubuntu everything is broken and `Err:8` has lnk but i removed http: from it as it was not letting me post it.

```
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210819) focal InRelease
Err:2 cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210819) focal Release
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs.
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                            
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                     
Hit:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                        
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                                              
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thomas-schiex/blender/ubuntu focal InRelease                                  
Get:8 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease [7,343 B]                                   
Err:8 //packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease      
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
Get:9 //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]                                                                       
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                   
E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210819) focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
E: The repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: I cannot update my ubuntu everything is broken and Err:8 has lnk but i removed http: from it as it was not lettting me post it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do remove the CD / DVD install as a source for apt-get packages when installing new features?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42441/how-do-remove-the-cd-dvd-install-as-a-source-for-apt-get-packages-when-install)

Comment: For your first error, see the above duplicate. Second error probably needs a GPG key.